# To use google server

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a android game designed by me. I want to release it to play store and want to know the name, phone number, mail id and score of the highest scorer at the end of day. How to link the game to google server to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This article is a good place to start:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/developing-mobile-games-on-google-app-engine-compute-engine/

It outlines everything you need to start work on a server-side to a mobile game, including high score tables.